# ¿Como Convertir un dato en "1" o "0" y sea registrado en un datagridcheckbox?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagrid

Soy nueva en programación y estoy aprendiendo practicando.

Lo primero que hice fue la conexion de sqlite con [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).
Luego almacene los datos("generado" y "no generado") de los campos "cpComprobante" y "cpEstado" en una tabla.
Necesito ayuda en como puedo mostrar los checks del dato("Generado") del campo "cpEstado".

En mi codigo he creado una columna Text para que muestre el check del dato generado, pero no se como, necesito una orientación, por favor, estuve averiguando de que debía convertir el dato en booleano, como debo de hacer eso, por favor?
trabajo en c# y sqlite

Este es el código:

```
private void CargarDatos()
{
    //DataAdapter: se utiliza para recuperar datos de un origen de datos
    //DataSet: se llenan las tablas
    SQLiteDataAdapter Adaptador = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select cpComprobante, cpEstado from Seguimiento", conexion);

    //reapresenta una tabla de datos en memoria
    DataTable Table = new DataTable("Seguimientooo");

    //Fill: ejecuta el comndo sql, llenando en el objeto "Table" con los datos
    Adaptador.Fill(Table);

    //El fuente de datos del DataGridView sea la tabla que se acaba de cargar
    Dgv_Seguimiento.DataSource = Table;


    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Titulo = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    Titulo.HeaderText = "TEXT";
    Dgv_Seguimiento.Columns.Add(Titulo);

}
private void Form_Seguimiento_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conexion = new SQLiteConnection("Data source=Seguimiento.sqlite");
        conexion.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Conexion Realizada");
        //El metodo CargarDatos se llamara en la conexion despues de abrir la conexion
        CargarDatos();


    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex )
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error");
    }

}
```

*Este es el Resultado que hasta el momento he obtenido:*
[image: Este es el Resultado que hasta el momento he obtenido]

Comment: Karen, debes [edit] tu pregunta para agregar mas detalles. Los comentarios son temporales. ¿qué valor tiene la columna "TEXT"?

Comment: @karen, podrías explicar de una mejor manera lo que deseas lograr.

Answer (score 1):

No deberias haber usado un string como tipo de dato del campo estado, sino definirlo como bool o bit de esta forma el mapeo es directo

Si sabes que 0 = "no generado" y 1 = "generado" no necesitas tener el texto en el campos de la tabla.

Recomendaria que cambies el tipo de dato de ese campo en la tabla y lo defineas como bool.

Otra alternativa seria convertir en el sql, usando el `CASE WHEN`

[Conditional Clauses Using SELECT CASE](http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg09.htm)

```
SELECT cpComprobante,
    CASE WHEN cpEstado ='no generado' THEN 0
        WHEN cpEstado ='generado' THEN 1
    END AS Estado
FROM Seguimiento
```

entonces puedes devolver un bool

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Leandro Tuttini, ya logre comvertirlos en 0 y 1, agradezco muho su apoyo, quería consultarle como esos 0 y 1 puedo enlazarlo para que muestre en un datagridviewcheckbox, por favor?

Comment: Otra consulta, la manera en la cual utiliza la estructura del Select Case solo funciona en SQLite o es parte del lenguaje SQL y puede aplicarse en cualquier gestor de bases de datos?

Comment: no podria afirmarte que vaya a funcionar en todas las db, pero en Sql Server es la misma estructura

Comment: el 0 o 1 es un tipo bool, no se si defines las columnas en tiempo de diseño, si lo haces agrega una del tipo checkbox indicando el DataPropertyName con esta columna. Si las columnas se definen automaticamente deberia mostrarte la columna como check